# loop localstorage data in react js and form API url params

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I have a below function in React to get the keys to form api url based on what is present in localstorage, this function works perfect but I want to optimize it and have a map function instead of duplicates.

```
getFiltersFromLocal() {

let formurl = (localStorage.getItem(videoUrl) ? '&' + 'videoUrl=' + localStorage.getItem(videoUrl) : '') 
            
+ (localStorage.getItem(tvenName) ? '&' + 'enName=' + localStorage.getItem(tvenName) : '') 
            
+ (localStorage.getItem(tvGender) ? '&' + 'tvGender=' + (localStorage.getItem(tvGender)) : '')
            
+ (localStorage.getItem(tvStatus) ? '&' + 'tvStatus=' + (localStorage.getItem(tvStatus)) : '')

return formurl

}
```

To optimize this, I have tried the below but no luck.

```
getFiltersFromLocal() {
const localfilterdata = {
            "data": [
              {
                "keysToCheck": [videoUrl,tvenName,tvGender,tvStatus,tvidFrom,tvidTo,tvsortorderFrom,tvsortorderTo,tvstartFrom,tvstartTo,tvendFrom,tvendTo,tvsearch]
              },
              {
                "apiparams": ["videoUrl=","enName=","tvGender=","tvStatus=","idFrom=","idTo=","sortOrderFrom=","sortOrderTo=","startDateFrom=","startDateTo=","endDateFrom=","endDateTo=","search="],
              }
            ]
        }
    localfilterdata.data.map(k => {
            let formurl = localStorage.getItem(k.keysToCheck) ? '&' + k.apiparams + localStorage.getItem(k.keysToCheck) : ''
            return formurl
        })
}
```

Note: This function will form the url based on the item in localstorage, and it will get appended to the url. Example url below

**[https://example.com/getTvList?size=20&page=1&tvStatus=INACTIVE&enName="sample"](https://example.com/getTvList?size=20&page=1&tvStatus=INACTIVE&enName=%22sample%22)**

**Using the function like below :**

url = FETCH_URL + '?size=' + stateData.pageSize + '&page=' + stateData.currentPage + this.getFiltersFromLocal()

Comment: Hi, based on your example to make it work, you probably need to map `localfilterdata.data.keysToCheck` eg `localfilterdata.data.map((k, index) => `.
Then using the index you can replace references of `k.apiparams` with `localfilterdata.data.apiparams[index]`.

Comment: @melc Thanks for the reply, sorry I am unable to get you. If possible can you share small fiddle or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just assumed you tried to do something like this,

```
const localfilterdata = {
    "keysToCheck": ['videoUrl','tvenName','tvGender','tvStatus','tvidFrom','tvidTo','tvsortorderFrom','tvsortorderTo','tvstartFrom','tvstartTo','tvendFrom','tvendTo','tvsearch'],
    "apiparams": ["videoUrl=","enName=","tvGender=","tvStatus=","idFrom=","idTo=","sortOrderFrom=","sortOrderTo=","startDateFrom=","startDateTo=","endDateFrom=","endDateTo=","search="]
}
localfilterdata.keysToCheck.map((k,index) => {
    let formurl = localStorage.getItem(k) ? '&' + localfilterdata.apiparams[index] + localStorage.getItem(k) : ''
    return formurl
}).join('')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have edited my question to give more clarity on my problem, please check if you can.